# Data dosn't get replicated in Solr 8.4 CDCR

Tags: solr, solrcloud

i have configured Solr 8.4 on 3+3 , 6 systesm across 2 Data center. Uses zookeeper ensemble external server in each region.

I could configure the solrConfig.xml for test collection as per Solr manual. Followed the instruction manual provided by solr website to start solrCloud in a sequence.

When i insert a single record (document) in primary he dosn't get replicated. The replication happens only after i restart solrCloud on all servers. This is a new collection i defined. I have updated records manually thru UI. Not indexed the collection.

Do i have to restart solr evry time i update ? why records get updated only while restarting?
Please let me know if you have come across this.
Note: i dint run an index. it was empty collection using defaukt configset . Added record from UI in document section

Comment: if you follow the steps mentioned on the solr cdcr page...it should work

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitBashetti . yes , i did follow the cdcr page. still same issue.

Comment: Did you check the logs if there is anything happening...

Comment: Are you issuing a (hard) commit after inserting the document?

Comment: Thanks for responding @AbhijitBashetti  . I am doing this for first time, novice to solrcloud. I seee the logs running on my windows cmd console. is there a way i can redirect this to log file. Do they get log in file ?

Comment: @MatsLindh . i insert the document from UI -> Collection -> document window. Were i need to do hard commit ? is it part process of updating the record ?. Thank You . Are you saying after hard commit it should update immediate in DR without restart of Solr process ?? Please let me know. Thanks again Mats

Comment: You have many factors playing into this - I'm not (very) familiar with the CDCR, but make sure you've configured your replicators and update logs properly: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/cdcr-config.html

Comment: ok @MatsLindh i will docuble check. Thanks